# Can I use includes in a firebase rule if I'm checking array?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql, firebase-security

I have a set of invites and I'm getting an insufficient permissions error.

### The Data

```
"inviteID" : {
  playerEmail: 'jon@doe.com',
  teamID: 'abcdefg'
}
```

and a team

```
"teamID" : {
  ...
  managers: [managerID, ...]
  ...
}
```

with the following queries:

### Team Manager

Query seems straight forward

```
db.collections('invites').where('teamID', '==', myTeamID)
```

but the rules have to check if the person querying is the manager ...

```
match /invites/{inviteID} {
      function isManager() {
        // managers is an array
        return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/teams/$(resource.data.teamID)).data.managers.includes(request.auth.uid)     
      }
            allow read: if (isManager())
    }
```

Does it matter that I also have this rule that will fail?

```
    // Allow user to read his own invites
    match /invites/{inviteID} {
        allow read: if (request.auth.token.email == resource.data.playerEmail)
    }
```

The second rule that matches the same document will fail because obviously the invites will not have the same email as the manager. I need this rule as a separate query allows users to query their invites.

Seems to not read, I'm having a permissions issue. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

So i changed the rule to

```
return request.auth.uid in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/teams/$(resource.data.teamID)).data.managers
```

and this seems to solve my permissions error